# how to convert Sting to ZonedDateTime in java

Tags: java, zoneddatetime

My input String do not have zone:

```
String formatter = "yyyy-MM-dd";
String zone = "Europe/London";
String date = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of(zone)).format( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(formatter));
System.out.println("date: " + date);
// 
ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(date , DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(formatter).withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()));
String after = dateTime.plusDays(1).format( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(formatter));
System.out.println("after: " + after);
```

My console print the 1st syso but after I have this error:

```
date: 2019-12-17
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2019-12-17' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain ZonedDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO,Europe/Paris resolved to 2019-12-17 of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.createError(DateTimeFormatter.java:1920)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1855)
    at java.time.ZonedDateTime.parse(ZonedDateTime.java:597)
    at com.id2s.application.business.service.impl.Sof.main(Sof.java:16)
Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain ZonedDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO,Europe/Paris resolved to 2019-12-17 of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.time.ZonedDateTime.from(ZonedDateTime.java:565)
    at java.time.format.Parsed.query(Parsed.java:226)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
```

Expected after `plusDays(1)`: `2019-12-18`

Comment: You have passed a date `String` only, but a `ZonedDateTime` cannot be parsed from just a date, it needs information about the time, too. The pattern needs to include `"HH:mm:ss"`.

Comment: @deHaar, it is not possible use default value `00:00`?

Comment: It is, I'll provide an answer soon...

Comment: Why are you using `ZonedDateTime` if you only care about the date, not the time? Use `LocalDate`, e.g. `LocalDate.parse("2019-12-17").plusDays(1).toString()` returns `2019-12-18`. No need for `DateTimeFormatter` or `ZoneId` or anything like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `ZonedDateTime` is an object aware of zone, date **and** time. You haven't provided any information about the time, so the `String` can just be parsed to an object aware of the date only.

However, you can use the beginning of a day in order to create a `ZonedDateTime` from a parsed `LocalDate` like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String formatter = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    String zone = "Europe/London";
    String date = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of(zone))
            .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(formatter));
    System.out.println("date: " + date);
    // create a LocalDate first
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(date);
    // then use that and the start of that day (00:00:00) in order to parse a ZonedDateTime
    ZonedDateTime dateTime = localDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()); 

    String after = dateTime.plusDays(1).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(formatter));
    System.out.println("after: " + after);
}
```

which outputs

```
date: 2019-12-17
after: 2019-12-18
```